# get the value from selectOneMenu JSF

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf-2

```html
<f:view>
 <h:form>
  <h:panelGrid>
   <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Create Order"/>
   </f:facet>
   <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="Customer Number : "></h:outputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.customerNumber}"/>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="Create With : "></h:outputText>
     <h:selectOneMenu id="createWith" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.createWith}">
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Without Reference" itemValue="noRef"/>
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reference" itemValue="ref"/>                            
     </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:column>        
    <h:column>
     <h:outputText value="Reference By : "></h:outputText>
      <h:selectOneMenu id="refBy" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.referenceBy}">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quotation" itemValue="quotation"/>
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Contract" itemValue="contract"/>
      </h:selectOneMenu>
     </h:column>  
     <h:column>
     <h:outputText value="Inquiry Reference Number : "></h:outputText>
      <h:inputText id="docNum" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.referenceNum}"/>
      <h:commandButton value="..." onclick="javascript:popUp('OpenRef.jsp',this)">                          
      </h:commandButton>
      <h:commandButton value="Load" action="#{SalesCreate.getQuotationListFromDb}">                  </h:commandButton>                        
     </h:column>           
   </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>
 </f:view>
```

Above is my JSP which contains `selectOneMenu`, I'm trying to enable the field `referenceBy` only if the user selects `withReference` in the previous field. Also depending on the value of `referenceBy` the values in the popup should differ i.e., id user selects `referenceBy` as `quotation`, values in the popup should be related to `quotation`.
the popup JSP contains a datatable with values from a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<f:ajax>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) to re-render the second dropdown on change of the first dropdown with help of the new JSF 2.0 ajax powers and use the `disabled` attribute to disable the second dropdown when the value of the first dropdown is not `ref`.

```xml
<h:selectOneMenu id="createWith" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.createWith}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Without Reference" itemValue="noRef"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reference" itemValue="ref"/>
  <f:ajax render="refBy" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
...
<h:selectOneMenu id="refBy" value="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.referenceBy}" disabled="#{SalesCreate.orderBean.createWith != 'ref'}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Quotation" itemValue="quotation"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Contract" itemValue="contract"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply...but can u also help me out in passing the value of second dropdown to the popup